# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse ./base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]

Tags: xml, apk, android-manifest

I am trying to pass in an apk file for test. I am having trouble with the AndroidManifest.xml. When I try to upload the apk it gives me this error:

> `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl1270000233.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]`

What am I doing wrong in this XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@ref/0x01030006"
    android:versionCode="13"
    android:versionName="1.0.6"
    android:installLocation="2"
    package="pl.techland.dyingLight.CA"
    platformBuildVersionCode="22"
    platformBuildVersionName="5.1-1756733">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:label="@ref/0x7f030000"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f020000"
        android:debuggable="false">

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="density|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:label="@ref/0x7f030000"
            android:name="com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
            android:launchMode="2">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.prime31.EtceteraProxyActivity"
            android:configChanges="0xd80" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.prime31.WebViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="0x4a0" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.prime31.P31VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="0x4b0" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.prime31.AlarmManagerReceiver" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.prime31.EtceteraPlugin"
            android:value="UnityPlayerActivityProxy" />


<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode" android:value="vr_only"/>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00030001" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your package name is wrong?
your activity from com.prime31.... and pacage is pl.techland.dyingLight.CA

Comment: The two namings are different one is for the package and one is for a part of the code that is used

Answer (score 0):

you might just need to clean the project before run

```
"clean:android": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ../",
"clean:ios": "cd ios && xcodebuild clean && cd ../",
"clean": "npm run clean:android && npm run clean:ios"
```